# How to deserialize abstract classes in jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to deserialize a JSON object to a Java object using jackson. The json was created using the jackson library itself by another developer and is provided to me. The Object graph has a variable of Type guava's ImmutableMap which is an abstract class.Hence jackson throws me the following exception when I try to deSerialize. I am not the owner of the myJava class and hence couldn't make any changes to it like changing the type or adding annotations by writing a custom deserializer.

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not find a
>   deserializer for non-concrete Map type [map type; class
>   com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap, [simple type, class
>   com.walmart.services.common.enums.ShipMethod] -> [simple type, class
>   com.walmart.services.shipprice.api.DetailedShipPrice]]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with Guava types, you will want to use Guava datatype module (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-guava). It is not a problem of just having abstract type; but Guava also uses builder-style instead of constructors.